# Slim php framework application fatal error

Tags: php, sql, frameworks, slim

I'm really sorry to bother you here but I wasn't able to figure out this problem.
After following one by one the instruction on https://github.com/ElanMan/simple-quiz I keep getting this error:

Fatal error: Class 'ORM' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/simple-quiz/public/index.php on line 4

I've tried everything. On Google the only results are about Laravel.
I'd be really happy if anyone could give me a hint.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run composer?

Comment: Yes, I followed all the instruction steps

Comment: Did you tinker with `composer.json`? This path `/home/ubuntu/workspace/simple-quiz/public/index.php` looks a bit strange to me.

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`